# PayPal PayFlow Test expired subscription

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I am fairly new to working with PayPal's PayFlow Pro API.  I want to work on a system to check   the status of a subscription and take action depending on the return values.  My issue is that you cant set an invalid number or a past expiration date to run the checks.

Does anyone know a way to force an account to appear VENDOR INACTIVE, EXPIRED, or TOO MANY FAILURES.

I cant believe they do not have a good testing system for this or proper documentation displaying the limited results mentioned in their pdf documents.

If there is no way to force them what setting does an account receive when a credit card transaction fails?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the profile set up and it has successfully billed, you could update the profile and use a bad credit card number to generate a failure.

Comment: You can not put in a bad credit card anymore.  They put in a system to authorize the card when you type it in.

Comment: You can.  Keep in mind that there are specific card numbers that are designed to work for Payflow testing.  You are correct that the system checks to see if the number you are entering in is in a valid credit card number format.  However, if you use a card number that is not one of the ones designed for testing, you will get a result code 12.  You can see what I am referring to, if you try to run a virtual terminal transaction using the card number (5422551661840752) which is not a valid Payflow testing card number but validates against the mod 10 check.

Comment: My issue is that I am running an internal cron job that checks the status of a subscription.  If the card fails I have no way of knowing what the return code is going to be. Thats was the second part of my question.  If the transaction fails does it change the subscription status to VENDOR INACTIVE or does it remain active.